# What is the default behavior of Keras model.compile metrics parameter?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

The default value for Keras model.compile metrics parameter is metrics=None. There are a plenty of explanations and information about this parameter different values, and I believe I pretty much understand their meaning and purpose, but what I struggle finding, is what is the behavior of the default value metrics=None.

The official documentation of the model.compile method [here](https://keras.io/models/model/) doesn't say anything about the default value (which is None), and googling about it for a while hasn't brought any enlightenment for me either so far.

I'd be greatful for any helpful hint on this!

Comment: New link to `model.compile()` docs: https://keras.io/api/models/model_training_apis/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means it will not calculate any metric, it is not necessary to specifiy a metric. The only parameters that need to be specified are optimizer and loss.

These are the only things necessary to train a model, the metric doesn't go into the calculation for backpropagation.

By not specifing metric, simply no metric will be calculated. A metric is something extra that is calculated for you to simbolize how well a problem is being solved. Usually for classification you would use cross entropy.